# MongoDB: Create index with just one unique property

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a `users` collection with:

```
{
   email: string;
   name: string;
   surname: string;
}
```

I want make `email`, `name` and `surname` indexed for improve search speed, but only `email` a unique field, eg.:

```
// email as unique
db.users.createIndex( { "email": 1 }, { unique: true } );
// name and surname are just index
db.users.createIndex( { "name": 1, "surname": 1 } );
```

How make this?

*Side note: the search it is by single or multiple fields...*

Comment: You don't need a unique field to create an index. Your indexes should be based upon what you are searching. What are you searching _and_ what the search criteria is going to be like?

Comment: @prasad_ i want email to be unique for security reason and name and surname also indexed for search speed...

Comment: _"... name and surname also indexed for search speed"_. Individually?

Comment: both, if it is possible... the search is by single or multiple fields...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create indexes on fields based upon your search requirement.

If you are searching with `name` and `surname` individually, then create two *single field indexes*.

If you are searching `name` and `surname` together (in that order), then create a *compound index* with both the fields: `{ name: 1, surname: 1 }`. This *compound index* will cover searches with `name` and `surname` together, and also `name` only. For example both the following queries use the index:

```
db.collection.find({ name: "John", surname: "Doe" })
db.collection.find({ name: "John" })
```

In case the order of fields is `surname` and `name` then the index should be on `{ surname: 1, name: 1 }`. This will also cover searches with `surname` only, when searched for a single field. For example, these two queries benefit by the index:

```
db.collection.find({ name: "John", surname: "Doe" })
db.collection.find({ surname: "Doe" })
```

Finally, the index on `email` as an *unique* index works for both the searching and applying the uniqueness on the field.

See:

- [Compound Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/core/index-compound/index.html): See the sub-topic on *Prefixes*.
- [Unique Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/core/index-unique/index.html)

You can verify if an index is used for a particular query by generating a *query plan* on the query - use the [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/method/db.collection.explain/index.html) method.